# Prevent activity from being destroyed on back button pressed

Tags: android, android-activity, ondestroy

I'm using an Activity A as a menu to access activity B.

The initialization of Activity B is quite long (1.5 sec approximatively). This is due to the creation of a custom adapter and the gathering of data and insertion of those into a listview.

The user is often  likely to go back to Activity A and then to Activity B.

I want to prevent my Activity B to be destroyed so the activity won't have to launch more than once during the application process (in order to accelerate the display of Activity B).

As I saw, Android does not work that way, Activity has cycles and it's normal for it to be destroyed.

So, if I want to respect that aspect of Android development, how to accelerate the launch of my activity ? Using onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState may be enough already ?

Answer (score 1):

override back key of device in your class

```
    @Override
       public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

         }
      return false; 
 }
```

Comment: That doesn't destroy the activiy, exactly. But I also want to go back to the previous activity after back button is being pressed. And I want to reuse the activity B (the one not destroyed) after that if the user wants to go to activity B.

Comment: Well if you want to go to the previous activity, then just do so in the onKeyDown method, as you always would do when switching activities (i.e. startActivity)

Answer (score 0):

How is the data kept in activity B?

keep the data static in activity B, but make sure you do not leak a context of application.